# How to make a lagging cumulative list of items in pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd    
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : ['2020-08-01', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-07', 
              '2020-08-02', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-10'],
    'user_id' : ['u123', 'u123', 'u123', 
                 'u321', 'u321', 'u321'],
    'item_id' : ['i1', 'i2', 'i3',
                 'i3', 'i1', 'i2' ],
    'like' : [1, 1, 0, 
             0, 1, 0]
})
```

[image: Original_df]

My goal is to get to a dataframe like this

[image: Desired_df]

For each row, I want 3 new columns:

1. List of all previously liked items (like == 1 and date of previously liked items for that user < current date of the row)
2. List of all previously disliked items (like == 0 and date of previously disliked items for that user < current date of the row)
3. Mean of the column 'like' for all previous interactions (date of previous interactions < current date of the row)

More infos :

- My complete dataframe is very big so I'm looking for an efficient way to do this in term of memory and computational costs
- The data is already ordered by date and by user_id
- I have no problem using other librairies than pandas
- I have access to a multithreaded cpu and to a GPU

Here's a non-efficient code to achieve what I'm trying to do. Do you have suggestions on how I can improve this ?

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : ['2020-08-01', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-07', 
              '2020-08-02', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-10'],
    'user_id' : ['u123', 'u123', 'u123', 
                 'u321', 'u321', 'u321'],
    'item_id' : ['i1', 'i2', 'i3',
                 'i3', 'i1', 'i2' ],
    'like' : [1, 1, 0, 
             0, 1, 0]
})

d1['previously_liked_item_ids'] = ""
d1['previously_disliked_item_ids'] = ""
d1['previous_like_avg'] = ""

for index, row in d1.iterrows():
    d1_u = d1[(d1.user_id == row['user_id']) & (d1.date < row['date'])]
    d1.at[index, 'previously_liked_item_ids'] = d1_u[d1_u.like == 1].item_id,
    d1.at[index, 'previously_disliked_item_ids'] = d1_u[d1_u.like == 0].item_id,
    d1.at[index, 'previous_like_avg'] = d1_u.like.mean()
print(d1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this and please report the performance on your dataset:

```
d1['prev_liked_item_ids'] = d1[['item_id', 'like']].apply(lambda p: [p[0]] if p[1] > 0 else [], axis=1)
d1['prev_liked_item_ids'] = d1.groupby('user_id')['prev_liked_item_ids'].apply(lambda g: g.shift(fill_value=[[]]).cumsum())

d1['prev_disliked_item_ids'] = d1[['item_id', 'like']].apply(lambda p: [p[0]] if p[1] == 0 else [], axis=1)
d1['prev_disliked_item_ids'] = d1.groupby('user_id')['prev_disliked_item_ids'].apply(lambda g: g.shift(fill_value=[[]]).cumsum())

prev_num_liked_items = d1['prev_liked_item_ids'].apply(len)
prev_num_disliked_items = d1['prev_disliked_item_ids'].apply(len)
d1['prev_like_freq'] = prev_num_liked_items / (prev_num_liked_items + prev_num_disliked_items)
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is working and I get a huge speed up compared to my code. Do you think it's possible to multithread this code to get even more speed up ?

Comment: Yes, you could use this https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

@KroshkaKartoshka has a much shorter solution than mine.  But `.apply()` can be relatively slow, so here is a different approach. I used self-join to obtain the new columns.

```
# use the original Dataframe `d1`
# You might be able to generate these three data frames in separate processes.

kwargs = {'how': 'inner', 'on': 'user_id', 'suffixes': ('', '_y')}

prev_liked = (
    d1.merge(right=d1.query('like == 1').drop(columns='like'), **kwargs)
    .loc[lambda x: x['date'] > x['date_y']]
    .groupby(['date', 'user_id', 'item_id'])['item_id_y'].apply(list)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={'item_id_y': 'prev_liked'}))

prev_not_liked = (
    d1.merge(right=d1.query('like == 0').drop(columns='like'), **kwargs)
    .loc[lambda x: x['date'] > x['date_y']]
    .groupby(['date', 'user_id', 'item_id'])['item_id_y'].apply(list)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={'item_id_y': 'prev_not_liked'}))

avg = (d1.merge(right=d1, **kwargs)
       .loc[lambda x: x['date'] > x['date_y']]
       .groupby(['date', 'user_id', 'item_id'], as_index=False)['like_y'].mean()
       .rename(columns={'like_y': 'prev_avg'})
)
```

Now, assemble the results.  This is already a wall of text, so I didn't convert NaN to empty lists.

```
kwargs = {'how': 'left', 'on': ['date', 'user_id', 'item_id']}
result = (d1.merge(right=prev_liked,     **kwargs)
            .merge(right=prev_not_liked, **kwargs)
            .merge(right=avg,            **kwargs))
print(result)

         date user_id item_id  like prev_liked prev_not_liked  prev_avg
0  2020-08-01    u123      i1     1        NaN            NaN       NaN
1  2020-08-03    u123      i2     1       [i1]            NaN       1.0
2  2020-08-07    u123      i3     0   [i1, i2]            NaN       1.0
3  2020-08-02    u321      i3     0        NaN            NaN       NaN
4  2020-08-04    u321      i1     1        NaN           [i3]       0.0
5  2020-08-10    u321      i2     0       [i1]           [i3]       0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def previously_like(user_id, date):
    return d1[(d1["user_id"]==user_id) & (d1["date"]<date) & (d1["like"]==1)]["item_id"].tolist()
def previously_dislike(user_id, date):
    return d1[(d1["user_id"]==user_id) & (d1["date"]<date) & (d1["like"]==0)]["item_id"].tolist()
def previously_like_avg(user_id, date):
    like_info = d1[(d1["user_id"]==user_id) & (d1["date"]<date) & (d1["like"]==1)].count()
    all_info = d1[(d1["user_id"]==user_id) & (d1["date"]<date)].count()
    return like_info/all_info

d1['previously_liked_item_ids'] = d1.apply(lambda row: previously_like(row["user_id"], row["date"]), axis=1)
d1['previously_disliked_item_ids'] = d1.apply(lambda row: previously_dislike(row["user_id"], row["date"]), axis=1)
d1['previous_like_avg'] = d1.apply(lambda row: previously_like_avg(row["user_id"], row["date"]), axis=1)
d1
```